# Common functions and helpers ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I don't get something, and if somebody can clarify:

I need to access this function / helper from here and there:

```
namespace Laf.Helpers
{
    public class Common
    {
        public string TimeSpanToString(TimeSpan val)
        {
            return val.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
        }
    }
}
```

And in my controller I access it by:

```
var tmp = new Common();
string str = tmp.TimeSpanToString(tp.DepartureTime);
transferPoint.Add(
    new ListTransferPointVM { PortName = tp.PortName, DepartureTime = str }
str);
```

And the question is how can I achieve and not have duplicate in every controller:

```
DepartureTime = TimeSpanToString(tp.DepartureTime)
```

**Possible Answer**
I just found a way that compiler is not frowning on:

```
public class TransferController : Controller
{
    private Common common = new Common();

    public ActionResult Index ()
    {
      ...
```

and later, when I need it:

```
string time = common.TimeSpanToString((TimeSpan)variable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your method `string TimeSpanToString(TimeSpan)` a `static` method. This way you can access it without having to make a `Common` object. Your code will look as follows:

```
namespace Laf.Helpers
{
    public class Common
    {
        public static string TimeSpanToString(TimeSpan val)
        {
            return val.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
        }
    }
}
```

And your Controller:

```
transferPoint.Add(
    new ListTransferPointVM { 
        PortName = tp.PortName, 
        DepartureTime = Common.TimeSpanToString(tp.DepartureTime) }
    Common.TimeSpanToString(tp.DepartureTime));
```

EDIT: As suggested by Michael Petrotta an extension method would be better. An implementation could be:

```
namespace LaF.ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string TimeSpanToString(this TimeSpan ts)
        {
            return ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
        }
    }
}
```

You can now call the method like:

```
tp.DepartureTime.TimeSpanToString();
```

[More on Extension Methods in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: An extension method would be even better.

Comment: To the TimeSpan class? I agree. I had not thought about that solution yet, thanks!

Comment: And I agree with MichaelPetrotta. That didn't came to mind to. And to @Simon: I was searching for months to achieve this and no luck. I have started to do more complex app and I need this, and... Didn't see tree from the forest :( Thanks a bunch